# Java multiple classepath with :classes directive

Tags: java, classpath

Should be kind of trivial but say I have two `jar` files in `libA.jar` and `libB.jar` in directory `./lib`

```
java -cp ./lib/*:classes com.whatever.Start config.file
```

Runs smooth.

Now say those files are in distinct directories

```
/home/lib/libA.jar
./lib/libB.jar
```

I cannot start it with:

```
// this doesn't work
java -cp /home/lib/libA.jar;./lib/libB.jar:classes com.whatever.Start config.file
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux you should use a ':' as path seperator, not semicolon:

```
java -cp /home/lib/libA.jar:./lib/libB.jar:classes com.whatever.Start config.file
```

Comment: just perfect. Stupid me. Will accept as soon as SO let's me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
java -classpath /home/lib/libA.jar:./lib/libB.jar:classes com.whatever.Start config.file
```

Comment: actually linux, but I guess that may be irrelevant. Doesn't work because you're loosing the `:classes`. But also doesn't not work if you put it in.

Comment: @Frankie Try using ':' instead of ';'

Comment: With regards to your comment about classes, you can just add that in.  What I provided was an example.